# Weird behaviour on c arithmetics

Tags: c, double, long-integer

I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static double const x = 665857;
static double const y = 470832;

int main(){
    double z = x*x*x*x -y*y*y*y*4 - y*y*4;
    printf("%f \n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

The real solution of this is equation is 1. As already answered on a previous question by myself, this code fails because of catastrophic cancellation. However, now I've found an even more strange thing. It works if you use long longs, while, as far as I know, they have less range than doubles. Why?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I already pointed out that this is a 2nd question to a similar problem asked by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long long` has less range, but more *precision* than `double`.

However, that's not what's at work here.  Your computation actually exceeds the range of `long long` as well, but because of the way in which integer overflow is handled on your system, the correct result falls out anyway.  (Note that the behavior of signed integer overflow is not pinned down by the C standard, but "usually" behaves as you see here).

If you look instead at the intermediate result `x*x*x*x`, you will see that if you compute it using double, it has a sensible value; not exact, but rounded and good enough for most purposes.  However, if you compute it in `long long`, you will find a number that appears at first to be absolutely bonkers, due to overflow.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on that: The arithmetic of _unsigned_ integer types is defined by the standard so that the result of any computation involving only multiplications, additions and subtractions is correct modulo `2^BITS_IN_TYPE`. If, as is common, overflow of signed (two's complement) integers has wrap-around behaviour, the same holds for signed types (but, to reiterate, overflow of signed integers isn't defined by the standard).

Answer (score 1):

In a double there are bits for the mantissa and exponent. For large doubles the distance between two doubles (same exponent, 1 added to the mantissa) results, is much larger than 1. Hence you are in the same situation as infinity + 1 = infinity.

long long's will overflow, calculate modulo 2”, and hence the result when it should be 1 can indeed be one.

Comment: The standard does not guarantee that arithmetic on signed types is done modulo 2^n (though it is the most common behavior).  Overflow of a signed type is undefined.

Comment: @StephenCanon: good point; in Java it is defined modulo, but in C one should evade such things. As the C environment is much more heterogeneous, more compiler vendors/platforms.

Answer (score 0):

An overflow for a floating point type can either be considered undefined or an error, depending on language and environment. An overflow for an integral type simply wraps around (sometimes still yielding correct results, and sometimes not).

Comment: Overflow of a signed integer type is undefined.  Overflow of a floating-point type is fully defined if the implementation conforms to IEEE-754, which is common.